# mutate column based upon cumsum for a particular gouped by columns info using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
WC     ASN  TS  Date        Loss
7101    3   R   13-07-12    156.930422
7101    3   R   02-08-12    168.401876
7101    4   R   28-12-13    120.492081
7101    4   R   16-10-15    46.012085
7101    4   R   04-01-16    48.262409
7101    21  L   01-12-12    30.750564
7101    21  L   01-05-13    49.421243
7101    21  L   04-06-13    87.294821
7101    21  L   01-10-13    164.013138
```

And what I am trying is to use the code as shown below:

```
df %>% 
  select(WC, ASN, Date, Loss) %>%
  group_by(WC) %>% 
  arrange(WC, ASN, Date, Loss) %>%
  mutate(Days = Date - lag(Date))
```

To generate a new table something like this:

```
WC      ASN TS  Date        Loss        Days    Loss_A
7101    3   R   13-07-12    156.930422  0   156.930422
7101    3   R   02-08-12    168.401876  20  325.332298
7101    4   R   28-12-13    120.492081  0   120.492081
7101    4   R   16-10-15    46.012085   657 166.504166
7101    4   R   04-01-16    48.262409   80  214.766575
7101    21  L   01-12-12    30.750564   0   30.750564
7101    21  L   01-05-13    49.421243   151 80.171807
7101    21  L   04-06-13    87.294821   34  167.466628
7101    21  L   01-10-13    164.013138  119 331.479766
```

Here,

1. for each WC, ASN and TS (a ordered combination such as 7101, 3, 13-07-2012), the Days will be 0 for first row, and then it should be = recent_date - lagged_date
2. and Loss_A is calculated as cumsum until there is at least one out of  WC, ASN and TS (a ordered combination such as 7101, 3, 13-07-2012) is different.

How to modify the code in dplyr to achieve the final table as shown above?
`mutate()` is not working, as I wanted, when using `lag()`, is there better method to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
df %>%
  # start by making a date column that's a recognized date class so you can perform
  # operations on it.
  mutate(date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%y")) %>%
  # then group by all of the columns you want to use to id groups
  group_by(WC, ASN, TS) %>%
  # then compute the time intervals between rows using ifelse to deal with 1st rows,
  # and compute the cumulative total loss within each group.
  mutate(Days = ifelse(is.na(lag(date)), 0, date - lag(date)),
         Loss_A = cumsum(Loss))
  # drop the date column we created if you don't need it
  select(-date)
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 7]
Groups: WC, ASN, TS [3]

     WC   ASN    TS     Date      Loss  Days    Loss_A
  <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1  7101     3     R 13-07-12 156.93042     0 156.93042
2  7101     3     R 02-08-12 168.40188    20 325.33230
3  7101     4     R 28-12-13 120.49208     0 120.49208
4  7101     4     R 16-10-15  46.01208   657 166.50417
5  7101     4     R 04-01-16  48.26241    80 214.76657
6  7101    21     L 01-12-12  30.75056     0  30.75056
7  7101    21     L 01-05-13  49.42124   151  80.17181
8  7101    21     L 04-06-13  87.29482    34 167.46663
9  7101    21     L 01-10-13 164.01314   119 331.47977
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your efforts, but it does not return the table as i wanted (the last table above)

Comment: Where are you seeing differences between your desired output and the table this produces?